# How can I access sub domain file from the URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, sitemap

I have installed a wordpress on the http://zend.patidarweb.com/

I have a sitemap on the http://zend.patidarweb.com/sitemap_index.xml

and I want to access from http://patidarweb.com/zend/sitemap_index.xml

what I have to add in .htaccess so I get my problem solve?

Thanks in advance to all users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple redirect in the .htacces file, like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/zend/sitemap_index.xml [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://zend.patidarweb.com/sitemap_index.xml [R=301,L]
```

Or you need to use proxy, to avoid redirect & get the content only

Comment: Sorry! there was a mistake. Updated.

Comment: not better luck with your updated code... i also tried to make a redirect a url from the panel and try your code but no better luck.....

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled.! This code should work. I've tested it. Dont forget to add `RewriteEngine On`, and try moving this code to the top of the page.

Comment: yes I have rewrite engine on and get reference from wordpress .htaccess also and made some extra exp. but no luck yet!